# Customise the FlareClient.ts

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am currently trying to implement Flare in our Laravel and Vue project. So far everything works. Now I'm implementing a bypass to send Flare error reports to Flare even if an adblocker is active. I solve the whole thing with a proxy, in which I set the reportingURL from Flare to my API endpoint. But now I have the problem that the sendReport method of Flare does not send a scrfToken, which leads to a 419 status code. So far I have solved the problem with a global error handler:

```js
    import { flare } from "@flareapp/flare-client";
    
    export const initializeErrorHandling = (app) => {
        app.config.errorHandler = (err, vm, info) => {
            flare.beforeSubmit = (report) => {
                window.axios.post('/api/report-error', report)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log('Report successfully sent to the controller', report);
                        console.log('Response from the server:', response);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Error when sending the report to the controller:', error);
                    });
                return report;
            };
        };
    };
```

This sends the error report to my controller. However, I would like to do the whole thing without this error handler and instead somehow intercept the sendreport method and set a token. However, as I'm still new to the world of programming, I can't think of a way to solve the problem straight away. I thought of the proxy pattern or a similar mechanism to change the behaviour of the FlareClient without changing the class definition. Do you have any other ideas?
The sendReport method of Flare looks like this:

```js
 private sendReport(report: Flare.ErrorReport): void {
        if (
            !assert(
                this.config.key,
                'The client was not yet initialised with an API key. ' +
                    "Run client.light('<flare-project-key>') when you initialise your app. " +
                    "If you are running in dev mode and didn't run the light command on purpose, you can ignore this error.",
                this.debug
            )
        ) {
            return;
        }

        if (this.maxReportsPerMinuteReached()) {
            return;
        }

        Promise.resolve(this.beforeSubmit(report)).then(reportReadyForSubmit => {
            if (!reportReadyForSubmit) {
                return;
            }

            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', this.config.reportingUrl);

            xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('x-api-token', this.config.key);

            xhr.send(flatJsonStringify({ ...reportReadyForSubmit, key: this.config.key }));

            this.reportedErrorsTimestamps.push(Date.now());
        });
    }
```

You can find the FlareClient.ts here: https://github.com/spatie/flare-client-js/blob/main/packages/js/src/FlareClient.ts#L165